# Seg Fault when initializing cv::VideoCapture in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, mingw

I am using OpenCV 3.0 with Qt 5.5.0 using MinGW 4.9.2 as the compiler. Everytime cv::VideoCapture is initialized with an int, it causes a segfault. Below is as much relevant info as I could think of.

OpenCVViewer.h

```
    #pragma once

    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QTimer>
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

    class OpenCVViewer : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        OpenCVViewer(QWidget *parent = 0);

    public slots:
        void display_scene();

    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

    private:
        QImage      render_img;     /// Qt image to be rendered
        cv::Mat     original_img;   /// original OpenCV image to be shown
        bool    showImage( cv::Mat image ); /// Used to set the image to be viewed
        QTimer *timer;

        cv::VideoCapture cap;
    };
```

OpenCVViewer.cpp

```
#include "OpenCVViewer.h"
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>

OpenCVViewer::OpenCVViewer(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    cap(0)
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(display_scene()));

    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, throw exception
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open the web cam");
    }
    timer->start(30);
}

/** Rest of file not included */
```

Qt .pro file. OpenCV was compiled with MinGW 4.9.2.

```
 QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Humanactivity
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    OpenCVViewer.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    OpenCVViewer.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../lib/opencv/build/mingw32/bin/ -lopencv_calib3d300 \
                                                        -lopencv_core300 \
                                                        -lopencv_features2d300 \
                                                        -lopencv_flann300 \
                                                        -lopencv_highgui300 \
                                                        -lopencv_imgcodecs300 \
                                                        -lopencv_imgproc300 \
                                                        -lopencv_ml300 \
                                                        -lopencv_objdetect300 \
                                                        -lopencv_photo300 \
                                                        -lopencv_shape300 \
                                                        -lopencv_stitching300 \
                                                        -lopencv_superres300 \
                                                        -lopencv_video300 \
                                                        -lopencv_videoio300 \
                                                        -lopencv_videostab300 \
                                                        -lopencv_ffmpeg300
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../lib/opencv/build/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib/opencv/build/include
```

And the stack trace

> 0 QEdit!DllRegisterServer         0x14006cda
>   1 videoInput::start(int,
>   videoDevice *)            0x6bd84c6b
>   2 videoInput::setup(int)          0x6bd848be
>   3 cv::VideoCapture_DShow::open(int)           0x6bd8bfd5
>   4 cv::VideoCapture_DShow::VideoCapture_DShow(int)         0x6bd8c0b5
>   5 cv::VideoCapture::open(int)         0x6bd89e86
>   6 cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)         0x6bd8a2b7
>   7 ??          0x401901
>   8 ??          0x403d22
>   9 ??          0x4016f7
>   10    ??          0x401647
>   11    ??          0x4032f2
>   12    ??          0x404cfd
>   13    ??          0x4013de
>   14    KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk            0x7557337a
>   15    ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain           0x779f9882
>   16    ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain           0x779f9855   17 ??

Comment: does videoCapture work without Qt?

Comment: No it does not. For some reason I never thought to check

Comment: can you try to open the camera/device with VLC, GraphStudioNext or VideoInput library?

Comment: Yes. I can open it with VLC. Also I can open it with OpenCV in Visual Studio, though I can't use VS for the project with Qt.

Comment: does your qtCreator usw minGW? Did you compile OpenCV with minGW? Or can you try to use Qt in VisualStudio? For example use the QtForVisualStudio Add-In.

Comment: Yes for the first two. The last one I can't due to project contraints.